# Specifying contrasts using afex

Tags: r, anova, t-test, contrasts

I would like to understand how to specify a contrast in a follow-up analysis using the `afex` package. Below I included code from the documentation and explain why I do not follow all steps here.

*Edit*: I was doubting whether to post here or on stackoverflow. I decided to post here because I am also interested in understanding differences in output for different tests (aside from understanding how to use R-code to specify contrasts in afex).

Code from the afex [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/afex.pdf):

```
    ########################### ## 2: Follow-up Analysis ## ###########################
    # use data as above 
    data(obk.long, package = "afex")
    # 1. obtain afex_aov object: 
    a1 <- aov_ez("id", "value", 
                 obk.long, 
                 between = c("treatment", "gender"), 
                 within = c("phase", "hour"), 
                 observed = "gender")
    # 2. obtain reference grid object (default is uses univariate model): 
    r1 <- emmeans(a1, ~treatment +phase, model = "multivariate") 
    r1
    # treatment phase   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL
    # control   fup   4.333333 0.5511982 10 3.105187 5.561479
    # A         fup   7.250000 0.6038074 10 5.904633 8.595367
    # B         fup   7.291667 0.4611655 10 6.264126 8.319207
    # control   post  4.083333 0.6277716 10 2.684571 5.482096
    # A         post  6.500000 0.6876894 10 4.967733 8.032267
    # B         post  6.625000 0.5252314 10 5.454711 7.795289
    # control   pre   4.250000 0.7660323 10 2.543174 5.956826
    # A         pre   5.000000 0.8391464 10 3.130265 6.869735
    # B         pre   4.166667 0.6409086 10 2.738633 5.594700
    # 
    # Results are averaged over the levels of: gender, hour 
    # Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Based on this reference grid, I would specify the contrast `A_B_pre` (A vs. B, pretest) as follows: `c(rep(0, 6), 0, -1, 1)`. However, the documentation specifies the same contrast as `A_B_pre = c(0, -1, 1, rep(0, 6))` (which to me seems to compare A vs. B in the follow-up treatment):

```
    # 3. create list of contrasts on the reference grid: 
    c1 <- list( A_B_pre = c(0, -1, 1, rep(0, 6)), 
                # A versus B for pretest 
                A_B_comb = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0.5), 
                # A vs. B for post and follow-up combined 
                effect_post = c(0, 0, 0, -1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), 
                # control versus A&B post 
                effect_fup = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0.5, 0.5), 
                # control versus A&B follow-up 
                effect_comb = c(0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0.25, 0.25, -0.5, 0.25, 0.25) 
                # control versus A&B combined
    )
    # 4. test contrasts on reference grid: 
    contrast(r1, c1)
    # contrast       estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
    # A_B_pre      0.04166667 0.7597743 10   0.055  0.9573
    # A_B_comb    -0.35416667 0.8327863 10  -0.425  0.6796
    # effect_post  2.47916667 0.7624260 10   3.252  0.0087
    # effect_fup   0.33333333 0.9303431 10   0.358  0.7276
    # effect_comb  1.40625000 0.7337579 10   1.917  0.0843
    # 
    # Results are averaged over the levels of: gender, hour
```

For the comparison of treatment A vs. B in the phase pre, the estimate of the difference (based on the contrast from the documentation) is 0.04166667. However, when I calculate that difference, I obtain 0.8571429: <sup>1)</sup>

```
    mean(obk.long[obk.long$treatment=="A" & obk.long$phase=="pre",]$value, na.rm=TRUE) -
    mean(obk.long[obk.long$treatment=="B" & obk.long$phase=="pre",]$value, na.rm=TRUE)
    # [1] 0.8571429
```

As I mentioned above, to me it seems that the contrast from the documentation compares A vs. B in the follow-up treatment. Indeed, when I manually calculate this comparison in the follow-up treatment, I come closer to the output from afex, although I am still far away from an exact match:

```
    mean(obk.long[obk.long$treatment=="A" & obk.long$phase=="fup",]$value, na.rm=TRUE) -
            mean(obk.long[obk.long$treatment=="B" & obk.long$phase=="fup",]$value, na.rm=TRUE)
    #[1] -0.03571429

    t.test(obk.long[obk.long$treatment=="A" & obk.long$phase=="fup",]$value,
           obk.long[obk.long$treatment=="B" & obk.long$phase=="fup",]$value)
    #p-value = 0.9484
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>

*Edit 2*: When obtaining all pairwise comparisons (i.e., without using the contrasts specified in the documentation, I obtain 0.83333333, which comes relatively close to 0.8571429 (differences likely arise because I do not control for gender and hour here, see also below):

```
emmeans(a1, c("treatment", "phase"), contr = "pairwise", model = "multivariate")
#...
#$contrasts
#contrast                    estimate        SE   df t.ratio p.value
#...
#A,pre - B,pre               0.83333333 1.0559027 10   0.789  0.9946
```

---

Additional thoughts / bonus question:

Perhaps the difference arises because in the contrast for the afex package, hour and gender are controlled for? Usually I would regress the dependent variable (`value`) on these variables (`hour` and `gender`) and then use the residuals in the next analysis (i.e.,  the t-test), but in this case I receive only 16 residuals (16 residuals for each level of `hour`) instead of 240 residuals (1 for each observation). Is it possible to control for `hour` and `gender` in the t.test above?

```
    a2 <- aov_ez("id", "value",
                 obk.long,
                 between = c("gender"),
                 within = c("hour"),
                 observed = "gender")
    residuals(a2$lm)
    # X1         X2          X3          X4          X5
    # 1  -3.4583333 -3.4583333 -3.29166667 -2.95833333 -2.87500000
    # 2  -2.1250000 -2.1250000 -2.29166667 -1.95833333 -2.54166667
    # 3  -0.1250000 -0.1250000  0.04166667  0.37500000  0.45833333
    # 4  -0.8333333 -1.5416667 -1.37500000 -1.16666667 -0.70833333
    # 5  -0.1666667 -0.2083333  0.29166667 -0.83333333 -1.37500000
    # 6   2.8750000  3.2083333  2.37500000  2.70833333  2.79166667
    # 7   1.2083333  1.2083333  1.37500000  1.70833333  1.79166667
    # 8  -1.1666667 -0.5416667  0.29166667 -0.83333333 -0.04166667
    # 9  -0.5000000 -0.8750000 -0.70833333 -0.50000000 -1.37500000
    # 10  0.5416667  0.5416667 -0.29166667  0.04166667  1.45833333
    # 11 -1.1250000 -1.4583333 -0.62500000 -1.62500000 -1.20833333
    # 12  2.2083333  2.2083333  2.70833333  1.70833333  0.12500000
    # 13  0.8333333  1.1250000  0.29166667  3.16666667  2.29166667
    # 14 -0.1666667  0.1250000 -0.37500000 -1.50000000 -2.04166667
    # 15  0.5000000  0.1250000 -0.37500000  0.83333333  1.62500000
    # 16  1.5000000  1.7916667  1.95833333  0.83333333  1.62500000
```

Comment: What documentation do you refer to??? The contrast coefficients are always applied to the means as ordered in the grid. So your first impression is right.

Comment: Second, `emmeans()` computes predictions from the model, and those may not be the same as ordinary marginal means, as you are seeing happens. Read `vignette(“basics”, package = “emmeans”)`

Comment: @rvl: The package documentation in this link (on p. 16/17): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/afex.pdf. Ah, that explains the slight difference.

Comment: Suggest reporting this to Henrik. Seems like a documentation blurp, or he’d meant to make phase an ordered factor.

Comment: @rvl Indeed a mistake in the documentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot for reporting this. It is indeed a mistake in the documentation. This and all the following contrasts were wrong. I guess when I wrote the code the ordering of the factor was different or I just made a stupid error. Sorry for that.

The latest [development version on github](https://github.com/singmann/afex) now does it correctly:

```
[...]
> r1 <- emmeans(a1, ~treatment +phase, model = "multivariate")
> r1
 treatment phase   emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 control   fup   4.333333 0.5511982 10 3.105187 5.561479
 A         fup   7.250000 0.6038074 10 5.904633 8.595367
 B         fup   7.291667 0.4611655 10 6.264126 8.319207
 control   post  4.083333 0.6277716 10 2.684571 5.482096
 A         post  6.500000 0.6876894 10 4.967733 8.032267
 B         post  6.625000 0.5252314 10 5.454711 7.795289
 control   pre   4.250000 0.7660323 10 2.543174 5.956826
 A         pre   5.000000 0.8391464 10 3.130265 6.869735
 B         pre   4.166667 0.6409086 10 2.738633 5.594700

Results are averaged over the levels of: gender, hour 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
> c1 <- list(
+   A_B_pre = c(rep(0, 6), 0, -1, 1),  # A versus B for pretest
+   A_B_comb = c(-0.5, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), # A vs. B for post and follow-up combined
+   effect_post = c(0, 0, 0, -1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0), # control versus A&B post
+   effect_fup = c(-1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), # control versus A&B follow-up
+   effect_comb = c(-0.5, 0.25, 0.25, -0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0, 0, 0) # control versus A&B combined
+ )
> contrast(r1, c1)
 contrast      estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
 A_B_pre     -0.8333333 1.0559027 10  -0.789  0.4483
 A_B_comb     2.6666667 0.7962586 10   3.349  0.0074
 effect_post  2.4791667 0.7624260 10   3.252  0.0087
 effect_fup   2.9375000 0.6694279 10   4.388  0.0014
 effect_comb  2.7083333 0.6519868 10   4.154  0.0020

Results are averaged over the levels of: gender, hour
```

You can install it via: `devtools::install_github("singmann/afex@master")`

Please let me know if you find other errors.